# Assigning EJB to a variable and returning

Tags: java, methods, reference, ejb, return

I have a factory pattern implementation.

```
 class FactoryValidator {
    @EJB
    FieldValidator fv;

    @EJB
    MethodValidator mv;

    public Validator getValidator(VType type){
        Validator v = null

        switch(type) {
        case FIELD:
            v = fv; break;
        case METHOD:
            v = mv;break;
        }

        return v;
    }
 }
```

Is it a okay to return EJB reference like above? Or is there a better way to handle this?
I know you can return the EJB directly from case statement. But I guess thats not a good practice.

Thoughts?

Comment: Few things: there's no `m` variable in your class/code (probably you meant `v`); your `switch` needs `break`s statements at the end of each case.

Comment: ah. thanks. fast typing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you are returning reference to stub, which instead of pointing directly on EJB bean object, points to an element on JNDI tree. In my opinion this is not a bad practice, but you have to be careful, because:

1. All invocations on this factory in case of SFSB will reference same bean instance, which  can be discarded any time (in case of exception, or invocation of @Remove method)
2. EJB stub will work only if JNDI context is valid, which as I remember is bound to the thread.

I used that kind of solution when I needed EJB Timers in CDI services, and worked well.